# Struts2 jQuery tag select not loading data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am trying to use `<sj:select>` tag to render my list in Struts2 JSP.

At the same location I have used a `<s:select>` tag as well

Data is getting populated in the `<s:select>` tag whereas no data is being populated in the `<sj:select>` tag.

- struts2-jquery-plugin ver: 3.7.0
- jQuery UI: 1.8.2
- struts2-json-plugin ver:2.3.16.3

This is also used:

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true" />
```

A normal use of Struts2 `<s:select>` tag, gives me result

```
<s:select list="languageList"></s:select>
```

but in the same jsp but just a another div gives nothing even when the same object (List) *here named*, `languageList` is used, as shown in the snippets

```
        <s:url id="remoteurl" action="sample2"/> 
    <sj:select 
        href="%{remoteurl}" 
        id="echo" 
        name="echo" 
        list="languageList" 
        emptyOption="true" 
        ="-1" 
        headerValue="Please Select a Language"
/>
```

Have edited the question as per the suggestion.

I mean to say that the action class is returning the object `languageList` but the UI in jsp is not being able to render one, please check snapshot from the O/P screen for understanding better.

Please help me figure out what is wrong here?

I was trying to replicate the tutorial on struts jQuery select as shown in the link: http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

**JSP:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Double Combo</title>

<sj:head jqueryui="true" />
<sb:head includeScripts="true" includeScriptsValidation="true" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
    content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<!-- begin jquery -->

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jq/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jq/functions.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="simple">
        <s:select list="languageList"></s:select>
    </div>

    <s:form id="formSelectOne" action="echo" theme="simple"
        cssClass="yform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>AJAX Form populated by a String List</legend>
            <div class="type-text">
                <label for="echo">Echo: </label>
                <s:url id="remoteurl" action="sample2" />
                <sj:select href="%{remoteurl}" id="echo" name="echo"
                    list="languageList" emptyOption="true" headerKey="-1"
                    headerValue="Please Select a Language" />
            </div>
            <div class="type-button">
                <sj:submit targets="result1" value="AJAX One" indicator="indicator"
                    button="true" />
                <img id="indicator" src="images/indicator.gif" alt="Loading..."
                    style="display: none" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </s:form>

    

</body>
</html>
```

**Action Class:**

```
package com.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.*;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
@ParentPackage( value = "showcase")
public class Sample extends ActionSupport{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2223948287805083119L;
    private List<String> languageList;
    private List<ListValue> languageObjList;
    private Map<String, String> languageMap;

    @Actions({
        @Action(
        value="/sample2", 
        results={
        @Result(name="success",type="json")
        }) 
    })
    public String execute() {
        
      languageList = new ArrayList<String>();
      languageObjList = new ArrayList<ListValue>();
      languageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
         
      languageList.add("Java");
      languageList.add("PHP");
      languageList.add("C++");
       
      languageMap.put("J", "Java");
      languageMap.put("P", "PHP");
      languageMap.put("C", "C++");

      languageObjList.add(new ListValue("J", "Java"));
      languageObjList.add(new ListValue("P", "PHP"));
      languageObjList.add(new ListValue("C", "C++"));

      return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getJSON(){
        return execute();
    }

    public List<String> getLanguageList()
    {
      return languageList;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getLanguageMap()
    {
      return languageMap;
    }
    
    public List<ListValue> getLanguageObjList()
    {
      return languageObjList;
    }

    public class ListValue {
    private String myKey;
    private String myValue;

    public ListValue(String myKey, String myValue) {
      super();
      this.myKey = myKey;
      this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    public String getMyKey()
    {
      return myKey;
    }

    public void setMyKey(String myKey)
    {
      this.myKey = myKey;
    }

    public String getMyValue()
    {
      return myValue;
    }

    public void setMyValue(String myValue)
    {
      this.myValue = myValue;
    }
  }

}
```

**Action Sample2 returns this json:**

```
{"JSON":"success","languageList":["Java","PHP","C++"],"languageMap":{"P":"PHP","C":"C++","J":"Java"},"languageObjList":[{"myKey":"J","myValue":"Java"},{"myKey":"P","myValue":"PHP"},{"myKey":"C","myValue":"C++"}]}
```

Comment: Hi, code snippets are for providing runnable demos using HTML/CSS/JS. For others, use the normal code block. Also why was this tagged jquery ui..? why is this even tagged jquery..? Where are you using jQuery..? I am not able to understand your question...

Comment: Sorry I am a novice here ,

Comment: You're including jQuery, jQuery ui etc in your code, and tagging the question with the same. But you haven't shared any code where you use jQuery or jQuery ui, other than some struts tags... It's very hard to understand your problem as it is... please go through [ask] and try to rephrase the question... :)

Comment: Hello T J , I have added the code snippets and the refrence url which I am trying to implement,

Hope you will be able to understand the question now

Comment: @javaguy You don't need to post a code from a known application, they have pre-built war file available for download.

Comment: @RomanC Ya they have a pre-built war but I was trying to implement the same in my application and it is not working in my application, Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

May this be of some help to others,

All I had to do was change the `web.xml` as below:

```
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
```

Earlier I had set the filter as

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
```

So the *struts2-jquery tag* could not find the corresponding *.js* files

Solution:  change from  `<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>` to  `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
Thus, please be sure to check the `web.xml` for such anomalies which often go overlooked as in my case.

Comment: However , I am able to make a single select tag work but When I try to implement a two fold select on which the first selected option helps prepare a list for the second select the appl is not working.

The action class is called on change of the first select menu but the selected value is not coming as null. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load jQuery twice, different versions might conflict with each other. This code is wrong

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jq/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jq/functions.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `sj:select` tag should work if your action returns JSON, but it uses old notation. Change it to

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="sample2"/> 
<sj:select 
    href="%{#remoteurl}" 
    id="echo" 
    name="echo" 
    list="languageList" 
    emptyOption="true" 
    headerKey="-1" 
    headerValue="Please Select a Language"
/>
```

Check that jquery, json plugins are on the class path and taglibs worked.

Comment: Tried that still it is not working. Seems like some error with <sj: tag because even the header value of 
 `  headerKey="-1" 
    headerValue="Please Select a Language"`

is not being displayed
/>

Comment: certainly some error as I am not being able to carry out a simple ajax div change example shown in the showcase.

Either my struts jquery plugin is not working or some configurations issues,
 Can someone help me , been stuck too long on this

Comment: I already told you to remove scripts that loading jQuery. Also you can remove `sb:` taglib and plugin, because they are not related to your problem.

Comment: Now you have to add `@Namespace("/") @ParentPackage("json-default")` to class or package and `@Action(value="sample2"...`

Comment: Thank You @Roman C , However it is still not working,
Furthermore I see error *404* on calls to .js files by the plugin.

I checked the console in firebug and found none of the .js files such as 
http://localhost:8080/Application/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.7.0
http://localhost:8080/Application/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.7.0

are not being found.

Comment: They should be loaded from the plugin.