# Struts2 JQuery Ajax using struts2-jquery tag issues

Tags: ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have been struggling for some time on using the struts2-jquery tag.

However, I have not being able to get a working solution of it.

I have attached the JSP , struts configuration and the Action.

Need someone to help me out on this.

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-jquery-tags" prefix="sj" %>
<html>
<head>
<sj:head/>
<body>
</head>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <s:url var="ajaxTest" value="/AjaxTest.action"/>
 <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxTest}" targets="div1">
      Update Content
    </sj:a>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="AjaxTest"
        class="com.functionality.MenuAction">
        <result name="input">/jsps/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsps/ajax.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

ajax.jsp

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```

MenuAction Action class

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class MenuAction extends ActionSupport{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

What other configurations need to be called?
struts2-jquery jar ver used : `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0.jar`

Comment: How you could use jquery plugin on invalid document? The head and the body is not the same.

Comment: Appologies @RomanC that was a copy paste error :(

Comment: I checked in Firebug and found that 
calls to all the .js files by the plugin such as 
_ http://localhost:8080/Application/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.7.0 _

and others are not reachable, a **404 Error** is shown
http://localhost:8080/Application/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.7.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [struts2 jquery tag select not loading data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456010/struts2-jquery-tag-select-not-loading-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

May this be of some help to others,

All I had to do was change the `web.xml` as below:

```
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
```

Earlier I had set the filter as

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
```

So the *struts2-jquery tag* could not find the corresponding *.js* files

Solution:  change from  `<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>` to  `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
Thus, please be sure to check the `web.xml` for such anomalies which often go overlooked as in my case.